# Should I worry about stopping/disposing WPF animations?

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, storyboard, dispose

I have a `UserControl` that when loading it starts:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StFlash" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" >
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="img" From=".3" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.6">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Basically it makes an image blink forever. **`When I remove that user control should I worry about stopping the animation?`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by possibility you must stop the Animation, because it will be played until the garbage collector does not destroy your UserControl, and it may take some time. For this purpose you may use the `Unloaded` event for UserControl.

For more information, see this link:

[`WPF Animations Tips and Tricks`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/18/wpf-animations-tips-and-tricks.aspx)